# How to catch potentially undefined variables with pylint or mypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, lint, pylint

```py
import time

if time.time() > 42:
    x = 1

print(x)
```

My IDE (PyCharm) warns me about `x` potentially being undefined:

[image]

But `pylint` and `mypy` do not say anything. Is there a way to make one of them complain about this situation too?

Comment: Why would a linter complain about this? You need s type checker. Use mypy.

Comment: @zvone Thanks! But `mypy` also does not complain about the above situation. I've adjusted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mypy has partial* support via the error code [`[possibly-undefined]`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html#warn-about-variables-that-are-defined-only-in-some-execution-paths-possibly-undefined), which you can enable through one of the following:

- The CLI when running mypy (`mypy <...> --enable-error-code possibly-undefined`);
- A [mypy configuration file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html) setting which looks like

  ```ini
  [mypy]
  enable_error_code = possibly-undefined
  ```
- The [file-level configuration](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/inline_config.html) comment line

  ```
  # mypy: enable-error-code=possibly-undefined
  ```

See a [demonstration of your example in the mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=ce99a37c2c2d71e7af2f2852c4b67941).

---

**Partial*, because mypy treats annotated assignment statements as an implicit declaration of existence; it won't catch this example:

```py
import time

x: int  # Annotated assignment statement with no value set
if time.time() > 42:
    x = 1

print(x)  # No errors caught here
```

Note that, for all intents and purposes, this is good enough as full support. It's not possible for a type-checker to determine whether all execution paths can be met for (e.g.) independent conditional blocks; any more inference of `[possibly-undefined]` would result in a copious amount of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

While `mypy` seems not to report the potentially undefined variable, but would yield

```
C0103: Constant name "x" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
```

While not necessary on point, still better than nothing. Also note `mypy` is not really a linter you are looking for, but type checker.

Next, was `pylint` but it stays silent, despite presence of potentially relevant checker `E0602 (UnboundLocalError)`. I somehow failed to change that behavior on your code.

Digging deeper I found this old ticket on mypy's repo [Not detecting UnboundLocalError](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2400) which, despite the age is interesting read. I checked tools mentioned there and `pyright` raised the alarm:

```
test.py:6:7 - error: "x" is possibly unbound (reportPossiblyUnboundVariable)
```